# Modify `String`s via unsafe_ functions - Any caveat?

Tags: julia

```
julia> x = "abcdefg"
"abcdefg"

julia> GC.@preserve x unsafe_store!(pointer(x), 'A', 1)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x0000000118532160

julia> x
"Abcdefg"
```

I know it is a bit insane to directly edit a String which should be an immutable type.

But I'd like to ask why it's dangerous and in which case this will cause fatal errors.

Answer (score 5):

In every place that assumes string immutability. E.g.

```
julia> x = "abcdefg"
"abcdefg"

julia> s = Set([x])
Set{String} with 1 element:
  "abcdefg"

julia> GC.@preserve x unsafe_store!(pointer(x), 'A', 1)
Ptr{UInt8} @0x000000000a3043a8

julia> push!(s, x)
Set{String} with 2 elements:
  "Abcdefg"
  "Abcdefg"
```

This is just a quick problem. But breaking such invariant might have unpredictable consequences in general as code might (and will) assume that it is met.

Answer (score 5):

Realistically this will probably work, but theoretically any of a number of things are allowed go wrong

1. The update doesn't happen because the compiler decides to move computation that happens after the update to before the update
2. Some other string gets modified because the compiler was sharing memory between two strings.
3. You get cursed by an eldritch horror.

Of these, 1 is the most likely to go wrong.

Comment: These are good points. One of the things that is good is that `isimmutable(String)` is `false` so at least Julia does not see `String` as immutable. Still, it does not mean that the pattern OP asks about is good. It should never be used.

Comment: while this is true, I'm not sure whether it would be a breaking change for strings to be immutable (or for string mutability to depend on the length of the string) in the future.

Comment: related issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/30210